# WPF Popup window closed event

Tags: wpf, events, window

**Environmental summary:**
I encountered an obstacle with my Visual Studio WPF (not Core) app.
I created 2 different Windows, one of them is a MainWindow, where the software displays the data in ListBox with Binding, and the second one is a simply Add Data window.

In a MainWindow, if I click on "Add new element" button, it will show up the new window (mainWindow still displayed under), like this:

```
ModifyDetails details = new ModifyDetails(ListViewPositions.SelectedItem as Positions);
            details.Show();
```

If I finished with filling up my form I press the save button. It will update the Database, and close the window simply like this:

```
...Database updating...
this.Close();
```

So the problem is that I want to **Refresh** my ListBox after I close the "Add new element" window. I can Refresh it with a button on MainWindow, so the process is good, but I'm looking for an **Closing** event, or something to make it automatic.

Refresh process:

```
public void Refresh()
        {
            positions.Clear();
            positions = GetProducts();
            ListViewPositions.ItemsSource = positions;
            ListViewPositions.Items.Refresh();
        }
```

Comment: I think the best way to do that is to use an ObservableCollection as itemSource so that whenever a change is made to the list or an item in the list, the ListView is automatically refreshed. Otherwise maybe you can pass the MainWindow item as a parameter to ModifyDetails and then call your refresh method when you close the window. I am not sure if it is a good practice though

Comment: What about [`PopUp.Closed`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.primitives.popup.closed?view=net-5.0)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use this code :

```
ModifyDetails details = new ModifyDetails(ListViewPositions.SelectedItem as Positions);
details.ShowDialog();
Refresh();
```

or:

```
ModifyDetails details = new ModifyDetails(ListViewPositions.SelectedItem as Positions, this);
details.Show();


//get popup window
CurrentWindow _window;
public ModifyDetails(position,window)
{
   _window = window;
}


...database updating...
//this method define a parent Window => public void Refresh(){//do work...}
_window.Refresh();
this.Close();
```

I will give a supplementary example

```
public partial class Window1 : Window
{
    public Window1()
    {
       InitializeComponent();
    }
    
    private void btnGoWindow2_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Window2 wnd = new Window2();
        wnd.Show(ListViewPositions.SelectedItem as Positions, this);
    }
    
    public void Refresh()
    {
       //update elements...
    }
}  

public partial class Window2 : Window
{
    Window1 window1;
    int position;
    public Window2(int _position, Window1 _window)
    {
       InitializeComponent();
       window1 = _window;
       position = _position;
    }
    
    //other method ....
    
    private void btnCloseWindow_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        window1.Refresh();
        this.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much meysam asadi! The first one (ShowDialog) worked well. I have no idea how I forgot it, really. I tried the second one also, but VS couldn't find Refresh method neither with Window class nor with my window class. Thank you again!

Comment: I modified the code to make it completely clear to you